# Can GETH or similar nodes download just the most recent blocks ethereum (without having synced anything prior to those blocks)?

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes

A node that has not synced with the Ethereum block-chain, could they begin to just sync new blocks?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No. Geth can't do that (and no other client right now).

There is a experimental --light client mode where you don't download any blocks (but I wouldn't recommend it for anything important).

I would recommend using myetherwallet.com

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using a pool, you will need a full Ethereum node.

In a blockchain every block has a reference to the previous block to increase the security of the blockchain. In the case of a pool the required information is provided by them. A pool has access to a node, and can execute and validate transactions.